# Passing String Array - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays

I'm getting the exception i have posted below. I have tried changing the arguments passed in the constructor for a new Ballot object but haven't had any success. Also, the error also gives a line from the Ballot class, however I don't see any correlation to what it points to in the main. This is my first computer science class and I really appreciate the advice and sorry in advance that my code may not be super efficient/clean.

ERROR: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at Ballot.(Ballot.java:55)

at Assig4.main(Assig4.java:54)

**

> LINE 55: clicked[i] = false;
>     LINE 54: ballotsAr.add(new
>   Ballot(tempId,tempCategory,tempCandidates));

**

This is the text file that reads in at command line prompt:

2
33333:Best Guitar:Telecaster,Les Paul,Stratocaster,JazzMaster
23234:Best Amp:Jcm800,5150,Dual Rectifier,Plexi

```
/**
 * Alex Drizos
 * CS401
 * Main Class to execute voting e machine
 */

//import section
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Assig4 {

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {

        /* variables */

        String ballotsFile = args[0]; // gets the file name from command line
        JFrame theWindow; //assign variable name for main window
        ArrayList <Ballot> ballotsAr = new ArrayList<>(); //creates array for jpanel ballot objects
        JButton login, submitVote;
        int numBallots;
        int counter = 0; //to count each file read in loop

        /*create window*/

        theWindow = new JFrame ("Voting E Machine");
        theWindow.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        /* read in ballot info */

        //objects - open and setup scanner for file
        File myfile = new File (ballotsFile);
        Scanner textScan = new Scanner(myfile); // reads in date from text file
        numBallots = Integer.parseInt(textScan.nextLine()); //read in first line (number of ballots) and parse to int
        while (textScan.hasNextLine()) //one ballot's data for each loop
        {

            //read in each ballot's info
            //take the first line as a string
            String [] tempStr = textScan.nextLine().split(":");
            //parse line into proper data values
            int tempId = Integer.parseInt(tempStr[0]); //take first value for id
            String tempCategory = tempStr[1]; // take second value as category type
            String [] tempCandidates = tempStr[2].split(","); // takes the arbitrary number of candidates and splits into separate string variables

            //create ballot object
            ballotsAr.add(new Ballot(tempId,tempCategory,tempCandidates));
            counter++; //adds counter to while loop
        }   // end of loop to read in ballot text file contents
        textScan.close(); //closes ballots.txt file



        /*add Ballot panels*/

        for (int i =0; i<ballotsAr.size();i++)
        {
            theWindow.add(ballotsAr.get(i));
        }

        /*add local components*/
        submitVote = new JButton("Submit Vote(s)");
        login = new JButton("Login");
        theWindow.add(submitVote);
        theWindow.add(login);

        /*write actionListener class to handle login and vote submissions*/


        /*pack and set window to visible*/

        theWindow.pack();
        theWindow.setVisible(true);

    }   //end of main


}

//import section
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Ballot extends JPanel {

    //instance variables
    private int id;
    private JLabel categoryLabel;
    private String categoryS;
    private ArrayList <JButton> candidatesButton = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    private ArrayList<String> candidatesS = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int [] numVotes;
    private boolean[] clicked=null;

    //constructor
    public Ballot(int _id,String _category,String [] _candidatesS)
    {
        //set variables
        id = _id;
        categoryS = _category;
        for (int t= 0; t<_candidatesS.length; t++)
        {
            candidatesS.add(_candidatesS[t]);
        } //end of loop to copy array to arrayList
        categoryLabel = new JLabel(categoryS);
        numVotes = new int [candidatesS.size()];


        //align label
        categoryLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        // set layout for ballot panel
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,candidatesS.size()+1));

        //add the category label to the panel
        add(categoryLabel);

        //create action listener object
        ActionListener listener = new BListener();

        //loop to create arbitrary number of candidate buttons
        for (int i = 0; i < candidatesS.size(); i++)
        {
            candidatesButton.add(new JButton(candidatesS.get(i)));
            clicked[i] = false;
            candidatesButton.get(i).addActionListener(listener);
            add(candidatesButton.get(i));
        } // end of loop
    }   //end of ballot constructor

    //method to return click status
    public boolean getStatusClicked(int i)
    {
        return clicked[i];
    }

    //accessor methods
    public String getCategoryS() {return categoryS;}
    public String getCandidateString(int i) {return candidatesS.get(i);} //not right
    public int getNumCandidates() {return candidatesButton.size();}
    public int getId() {return id;}
    public int getVoteCount(int i) {return numVotes[i];}

    //mutator methods


    //listener to toggle the status of buttons when clicked
    private class BListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            int i = 0; //counter variable for arraylist calls
            for (JButton b: candidatesButton) //change to REGULAR FOR LOOP??
            {
                if (e.getSource() == candidatesButton.get(i))
                {
                    clicked[i] = !clicked[i];
                    if (clicked[i])
                    {
                        candidatesButton.get(i).setForeground(Color.RED);
                        numVotes[i]++;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        candidatesButton.get(i).setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                        numVotes[i]--;
                    }

                }
                i++; //increment int counter
            } // end of cycle through all buttons
        } // end of actionperformed
    } //end of listener

    //internal methods
    //private void printToFile(){;}

} // end of ballot class
```

Comment: Hi, can you tell us what Ballot.java:55 is and Assig4.java:54 is?  What line is that?  This will help deduce the null pointer.

Comment: I typed the lines for you noted by LINE 55: and LINE 54: directly after I copied the error message. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't refresh sorry ha.  One moment

Comment: Your array clicked is null.  You have the line  private boolean[] clicked=null;
 and then you are trying to set an index in it with  clicked[i] = false;  You will need to initialize this array before you can use it.

Comment: Thanks Kyle! I was too focused on thinking it something in the constructor line.

Comment: No prob.  I hope that fixed your issue.